# Classloader Java 11 migration issue

Tags: java, classloader, java-11

I am migrating an app from java 8 to java 11. I did most of the upgrade but got stuck with the following exception.

> class com.teamhub.plugins.sitemaps.jobs.SitemapUpdateJob cannot be cast to class org.quartz.Job (com...SitemapUpdateJob is in unnamed module of loader com...utils.ChildFirstClassLoader @bb39957; org.quartz.Job is in unnamed module of loader org.akhikhl.gretty.FilteringClassLoader @247667dd)

The application uses the normal context class loader but it loads plugins into the classpath using the ChildFirstClassLoader which on java 8 worked like a charm. In Java 11 though, it fails.
Looks like the issue is that the parent classloader loaded Job, and the child, ChildFirstClassLoader failes to use that to cast an implemented job.

```
public class ChildFirstClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    private static final Set<String> FORCE_IN_PARENT = new HashSet<String>();  //ImmutableSet.of("");

    private ClassLoader system;

    public ChildFirstClassLoader(URL[] classpath, ClassLoader parent) {
        super(classpath, parent);
        system = getSystemClassLoader();
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // First, check if the class has already been loaded
        Class<?> c = findLoadedClass(name);
        if (c == null) {
            try {
                // checking local
                c = findClass(name);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SecurityException e) {
                c = loadClassFromParent(name, resolve);
            }
        }
        if (resolve)
            resolveClass(c);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        for (String pkg : FORCE_IN_PARENT){
            if (name.startsWith(pkg)) {
                throw new ClassNotFoundException();
            }
        }

        return super.findClass(name);
    }

    private Class<?> loadClassFromParent(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // checking parent
        // This call to loadClass may eventually call findClass
        // again, in case the parent doesn't find anything.
        Class<?> c;
        try {
            c = super.loadClass(name, resolve);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SecurityException e) {
            c = loadClassFromSystem(name);
        }
        return c;
    }

    private Class<?> loadClassFromSystem(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        Class<?> c = null;
        if (system != null) {
            // checking system: jvm classes, endorsed, cmd classpath,
            // etc.
            c = system.loadClass(name);
        }
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public URL getResource(String name) {
        URL url = findResource(name);
        if (url == null)
            url = super.getResource(name);

        if (url == null && system != null)
            url = system.getResource(name);

        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {
        /**
         * Similar to super, but local resources are enumerated before parent
         * resources
         */
        Enumeration<URL> systemUrls = null;
        if (system != null) {
            systemUrls = system.getResources(name);
        }
        Enumeration<URL> localUrls = findResources(name);
        Enumeration<URL> parentUrls = null;
        if (getParent() != null) {
            parentUrls = getParent().getResources(name);
        }
        final List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<URL>();
        if (localUrls != null) {
            while (localUrls.hasMoreElements()) {
                URL local = localUrls.nextElement();
                urls.add(local);
            }
        }
        if (systemUrls != null) {
            while (systemUrls.hasMoreElements()) {
                urls.add(systemUrls.nextElement());
            }
        }
        if (parentUrls != null) {
            while (parentUrls.hasMoreElements()) {
                urls.add(parentUrls.nextElement());
            }
        }
        return new Enumeration<URL>() {
            Iterator<URL> iter = urls.iterator();

            public boolean hasMoreElements() {
                return iter.hasNext();
            }

            public URL nextElement() {
                return iter.next();
            }
        };
    }

    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
        URL url = getResource(name);
        try {
            return url != null ? url.openStream() : null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("ChildFirstClassLoader [system=%s, getURLs()=%s, getParent()=%s]",
                system, Arrays.toString(getURLs()), getParent());
    }
```

Comment: For a cast, the `Class` objects are checked on identity. When the same class is loaded by different ClassLoaders, you have two equal instances that are not identical. So this is giving you the CCE, as you assumed already yourself. But why the respective class is loaded twice … no idea yet. And the reason is not necessarily in the implementation of your ClassLoader itself. The question you need to answer is why the class is loaded twice.

Comment: @tquadrat I'd use different words, because class equality (`.equals`) is defined by the FQDN and its class loader. If the same class is loaded by different class loaders, the two instances are therefore *not* equal.

Comment: @RobSpoor – Jepp, in this context, it is really easy to screw up the terms 'equal', 'same' and 'identical'. Of course, based on the implementation of `Class.equals()`, the instances loaded by two different class loaders are *not* equal, because that implementation is based on identity only. Nevertheless, the bit pattern of the loaded code is the same, although it will *not* result in the same `Class` … have fun! 

Comment: Normal class loading never uses the context class loader. Also the phrase “loads plugins into the classpath” makes no sense; the classpath is not involved in what you’re doing at all. You also show the wrong mindset when saying “ChildFirstClassLoader fails to use that to cast an implemented job”. It’s not the class loader which does a type cast. It’s the method shown in your stack trace which does the type cast.

Comment: True, the cast is done in a different method. ChildClassLoader does the jar inspection and loading of the classes inside jar files. A method then tries to use the content loaded and assign it to another place performing a cast. When attempting to cast, it fails with the CCEx. It does not load into the classpath but parses the jar file and loads the classes in them, true. But the cause is the classloader from the child attempting to cast a class it loaded to a type loaded by the parent, if I am not wrong.

Comment: When class `X` contains a typecast like `(Y)`, then `Y` will be resolved in the context of `X`, i.e. using `X`’s defining class loader. Since `X`’s defining class loader is not your custom class loader, your custom class loader is not involved at all. The reason why it fails, is that class `Z` says to implement `Y`, but since `Z` has been defined by your custom class loader and your custom class loader is designed to resolve classes in its own context instead of delegating to the parent, it creates its own version of `Y`. So `Z` implements a different `Y` than `X` is casting to.